# How to import firebase and split its services into multiple split chunks using webpack?

Tags: javascript, firebase, webpack, webpack-splitchunks

Right now I'm doing:

**firebase.js**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/functions';
import 'firebase/storage';

const config = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

export default firebase;
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
optimization: {
  runtimeChunk: 'single',
  splitChunks: {
    chunks: 'all',
    maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
    minSize: 0,
    cacheGroups: {
      vendor: {
        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
        name(module) {
          const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];
          return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

The **webpack** part I got from this article:

https://medium.com/hackernoon/the-100-correct-way-to-split-your-chunks-with-webpack-f8a9df5b7758

And this results in this **small 667kb** JS file (this is the production version):

[image]

**QUESTION**

CanI import it in some other way so I could end up with smaller chunks?

For example:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import auth from 'firebase/auth';
import firestore from 'firebase/firestore';
import functions from 'firebase/functions';
import storage from 'firebase/storage';
```

But I have no idea what I'm going to do with those "extra objects", since the only one I need and use is the `firebase` object that I get from `firebase/app`

Also, if I import them like this and don't use the objects, wouldn't Webpack interpret them as "dead code" and tree shake them?

What's is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase loads these imports directly into the firebase object, there's no way to treeshake them from there. What you can do is optionally load these with dynamic import, webpack will then take care of codesplitting these. If not imported, these instances are not added to the firebase object so you can do a simple if check to load them in.

```js
export async function getFirestoreInstance() {
    if (!firebase.firestore) {
        await import('firebase/firestore');
    }

    return firebase.firestore();
}
```

When you need to use Firestore for example, simply call getFirestoreInstance

```js
async function doSomethingWithFirestore(){
   try {
      const firestore = await getFirestoreInstance();
      firestore.collection("foo") // do something with firestore
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should using my config. these config slighty reduce compiled file size.

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

/**
 * @type {import('webpack').Configuration}
 */
module.exports = {
    /**
     * The entry point file
     * [prevent duplication docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#prevent-duplication)
     */
    entry: {
        // shared utility
        shared: {
            import: ["bluebird", "crypto-js"],
        },
        // main script
        index: {
            import: "./src/index.js",
            dependOn: ["shared", "firebase", "internal"],
        },
        // all imported firebase module
        firebase: {
            import: ["firebase/app", "firebase/auth"],
            dependOn: "shared",
        },
        // internal/local utility
        internal: {
            import: ["./src/utils/index.ts"],
            dependOn: "shared",
        },
    },
    /**
     * The location of the build folder
     */
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
        chunkFilename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
    },
    /**
     * Prevent duplication
     * [docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#prevent-duplication)
     */
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: "single",
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: "all",
            cacheGroups: {
                styles: {
                    name: "styles",
                    type: "css/mini-extract",
                    chunks: "all",
                    enforce: true,
                },
            },
        },
    },
    // Optional and for development only. This provides the ability to
    // map the built code back to the original source format when debugging.
    devtool: "eval-source-map",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
                use: "ts-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules|.test.(ts|js)$/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
                    devMode ? "style-loader" : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    // Translates CSS into CommonJS
                    "css-loader",
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
                    devMode ? "style-loader" : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    // Translates CSS into CommonJS
                    "css-loader",
                    // Compiles Sass to CSS
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {
                            // Prefer `dart-sass`
                            implementation: require("node-sass"),
                            sassOptions: {
                                includePaths: [
                                    path.join(__dirname, "../node_modules"),
                                    path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules"),
                                    path.join(__dirname, "../../node_modules"),
                                ]
                                    .filter(fs.existsSync)
                                    .map((str) => path.resolve(str))
                                    .filter(function (elem, index, self) {
                                        return index === self.indexOf(elem);
                                    }),
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".*", ".ts", ".js", ".jsx"],
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
            // both options are optional
            filename: devMode ? "[name].css" : "[name].[contenthash].css",
            chunkFilename: devMode ? "[id].css" : "[id].[contenthash].css",
        }),
    ],
    /**
     * [Docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/)
     * @type {import('webpack-dev-server').Configuration}
     */
    devServer: {
        //static: path.resolve(__dirname, './public'),
        historyApiFallback: true, // enable react-dom-router support
        hot: true, // hot reloading
        port: 4000,
        open: false,
    },
};
```

my scripts `package.json`

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --no-open --mode development --config webpack.config.js",
    "prod:update": "cd page && npx npm-check-updates -u && npm install --omit=dev --production"
  }
}
```